# Range input field return wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

Here three time zone range input pakistan, afghanistan and india
here time zone offset in seconds

```
location       offset seconds
pakistan       18000
afghanistan    16200
indian         19800
```

input range 1 to 24 hour

when I click on any input the range displays all time according to their time zone.

But the problem is when I click on the afghanistan or india input time range it returns wrong time.
when when I click end the input range (mean 24 hour) it return 30 minute behind from the original value

```js
$("#comission div").on("click", "input", function() {
  var value = parseInt($(this).val())
  var hours1 = Math.floor(value / 60);
  var minutes1 = value - (hours1 * 60);
  var targetTime = new Date(0);
  targetTime.setMinutes(minutes1);
  targetTime.setHours(hours1);
  if (value > 1430) {
    targetTime.setMinutes(59);
    targetTime.setHours(23)
  }
  var timeZoneFromDB = $(this).find('.comissionLabel').attr("data-offset");
  $('#comission .time').each(function() {
    var timeZoneFromDB = $(this).find('.comissionLabel').attr("data-offset");
    var tzDifference = (parseInt(timeZoneFromDB) / 60) + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    var date = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60000);
    var totallv = parseInt(date.getHours() * 60) + date.getMinutes();
    $(this).find('.tooltip').css('margin-left', totallv / 3);
    $(this).find('.tooltip').html(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
    $(this).find('.comissionLabel').html(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
    $(this).find('.custom-range').val(totallv)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <br><br><br> <br><br><br>
  <div id="comission" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 44 time">afghanistan
      <span class="comissionLabel" data-offset='16200'>time: </span>

      <input class="custom-range" value="60" type="range" min="0" max="1440" step="15">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 45 time"> Pakistan
      <span class="comissionLabel" data-offset='18000'>time: </span>

      <input class="custom-range" value="620" type="range" min="0" max="1440" step="15">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 46 time">indian
      <span class="comissionLabel" data-offset='19800'>time: </span>

      <input class="custom-range" value="620" type="range" min="0" max="1440" step="15">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ID `comissionLabel` is repeated. ID's should not be repeated and only one of them will be taken into consideration.

Comment: there is js or time zone conversion problem, not an HTML and CSS problem  i'm using with this keyword $(this).find('#comissionLabel');

Comment: @M.Javid Maybe the time zone is the "main" problem, but having multiple elements with the same id is a big NO GO. just change `id="comissionLabel"` to `class="comissionLabel"` and your good

Comment: look my local time difference is 30 minute with India and Afghanistan this 30 minute have the problem for India and Afghanistan input range to decrease 30 minutes to the original time during the clicked time. otherwise HTML and all code working perfect

Comment: ok i have correct id="comissionLabel" to class="comissionLabel" but problem exist

Comment: i still see `id="commissionLabel"` in your html

Comment: Fortunately, Afghanistan, Pakistan, and India do not observe daylight savings time, so you can use a fixed offset for each one in order to display relative time. However, you need to decide how you want to deal with the relative dates so if it is 23:15 on 2018-12-19 in Afghanistan, it is 00:15 on 2018-12-20 in India (not sure how you want to handle that with your range controls and current output).

Comment: there is no fixed location it depends on the user which city to add there please give a solution